# How can I set the font in a select box in HTML?

Tags: html

I have a select and a button. Their default size in a browser is tiny. I want to increase the size of both for better visibility. I found how to make the button larger, but the same trick is ignored in the select. Any suggestions how to do this will be greatly appreciated.

```
<select id="selectFunction" size=3 onchange="readSelection()">
            <option value="0"> <style="font:bold 16px Arial"> z = r&#x00B2</option>
            <option value="1">z = r&#x00B4</option>
            <option value="2">z = x&#x00B2-y&#x00B2</option>
            <option value="3">z = 100xy-x&#x00B2-y&#x00B2</option>
            </select>
            
            <button type="button" style="font:bold 16px Arial"; onclick="draw()">Draw</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code you wrote:

```
<option value="0"> <style="font:bold 16px Arial"> z = r&#x00B2</option>
...
<button type="button" style="font:bold 16px Arial"; onclick="draw()">Draw</button>
```

They have different syntax. In `button`, you wrote the styles directly inside the `<>` encapsulating `button`. However, for the `option` tag, you wrote an entirely different tag `<style>`.

If you write it as below:

```
<select id="selectFunction" size=3 onchange="readSelection()" style="font:bold 16px Arial">
...
<button type="button" style="font:bold 16px Arial"; onclick="draw()">Draw</button>
```

You should be able to achieve what you want to do.

However, I assume you are a beginner to HTML/CSS and this is definitely not the most efficient way to go about styling your HTML. I suggest you read a little bit about CSS, [follow a tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp), something like that, before starting to write your code from scratch. It will help you a lot more than just trying it out and solving problems you encounter as you go.

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work either. The select is still shown at the default size. Yes, i am inexperienced  and I will follow your suggestion, but I'd like to solve this problem quickly, if that is possible.

Comment: I just checked, and you're right. Maybe `<option>` tags don't accept styling, but only inherit them from the parent `<select>`. If you put the styles in the same manner in `select` tag, it should work as intended. I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I found how to do this at https://tutorialdeep.com/live-editor/css-style-select-dropdown/